# bounjour, sockets creation for uploading data

Tags: iphone, ios, websocket, uploading

please provide easy study tutorials for beginners on socket creation for uploading data to web server via iphone app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing technologies in your question.

Bonjour is to broadcast and discover device over bluetooth or wifi.

If you want to simply upload data to your web server use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). Note that this framework is no longer being developed and maintained. But will work for you.

Lets say I want to upload the contents of my NSString property called data:

```
NSString *data = @"This is the text I will send to my server";
```

I provide the url for the data to be uploaded to:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/upload"];
```

I create a request that will handle the uplaod

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

I will upload my data using form request post value

```
[request addPostValue:data forKey:@"data"];
```

I will start the upload now and wait for it to finish (synchronous request)

```
[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error && [request responseStatusCode] == 200) {
    //If all is ok this is the response from my server
    [request responseString]];
}else{
    //If something went wrong this is my error
     NSLog(@"Error: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: thanks sir, u really helped me.. actually i am new for iphone app development and i am a electronics and communication engineering student want to come in mobile computing field.